# Simplify Boolean Expression: X + X'Y'Z

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I know that the following is equal:
X + X'Y'Z = X + Y'Z
How can simplify the left side to arrive the right side using basic Boolean identities?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just think about under which circumstance the right term is needed to get a `true` result, and which value X then must have.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pxx6M3gcc0Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expression                            Justification
---------------------------------     -------------------------
X + X'Y'Z                             initial expression
(XY'Z + X(Y'Z)') + X'Y'Z              r  = rs + rs'
(XY'Z + XY'Z + X(Y'Z)') + X'Y'Z       r = r + r
(XY'Z + X(Y'Z)' + XY'Z) + X'Y'Z       r + s = s + r
(XY'Z + X(Y'Z)') + (XY'Z + X'Y'Z)     (r + s) + t = r + (s + t)
X(Y'Z + (Y'Z)') + (Y'Z)(X + X')       rs + rt = r(s + t)
X(1) + (Y'Z)(1)                       r + r' = 1
X + Y'Z                               r(1) = r
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution/answer and the reference to the YouTube demo was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to prove this expression is to add a redundant term that will discard X'

```
X + X'Y'Z = X(1+Y'Z) + X'Y'Z
          = X + XY'Z + X'Y'Z
          = X + (X+X')Y'Z
          = X + Y'Z
```